# Linux "top": how to tell which process is what?

Tags: linux, unix, administration, system-administration

I have several cron jobs (calling my PHP scripts via `curl`) in the background that are running. I'm trying to monitor their performance. Using `top`, I see a bunch of `httpd` commands -- but I have a feeling these do not represent the cron jobs (e.g. too many httpd exit for the cron tasks being called).

How can I know what the httpd processes are for sure? Are there any other tools I should be looking at to monitor my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to look in /proc/[pid]/status.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a hierarchically overview about your running processes with `ps efaux` or `pstree -A -p`
Maybe that helps.